# wine4win alternative

Tags: games

I was playing this heroes of Newerth game back using a win7 OS. after reading some forum back in the HON blogs. some of the gamers could play using Linux

so I tried out the wine Microsoft program loader

the process goes smoothly until I downloaded everything - I started running things like I am on win7 but the game isn’t working. I cannot run the game, I am stock with the game launcher.(garena game launcher)

are there any options possible that I could play the game in Ubuntu?

processor: AMD A4-5300 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2 
OS type : 32 bit
dual-booted win7-ubuntu14

Comment: Why are you playing it using wine,it is also available for linux.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, HON now has a native linux client.
[download](http://www.heroesofnewerth.com/download/)